# Postgres link to Big Query using ODBC drivers

Tags: postgresql, odbc, google-bigquery, dblink

I'm trying to build a link from Postgres (Windows installation) to Google Big Query. In order to do so I've found 3rd party ODBC drivers by [Simba](http://www.simba.com/drivers/bigquery-odbc-jdbc/), installed and configured successfully. Next step was to create a link in Postgres. I was looking at *dblink* function in Postgres to do so. Documentation of *dblink_connect* states that I need to pass *libpq-style connection info string* which should be similar to `hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=mydb user=postgres password=mypasswd`.

Question is how should I create a dblink connection using installed ODBC drivers? What should be my `hostaddr` and `port`?

When I am googling for Postgres dblink connection using ODBC I always find how to connect **to** Postgres instead of **from** Postgres. Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could also simply install the FDW and query forign tables of bigquery: https://github.com/gabfl/bigquery_fdw

Answer (score 0):

Postgres [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) is a module that supports connections to other *PostgreSQL* databases. It doesn't support ODBC data sources.

You may want to try [ODBC-Link](http://www.cybertec.at/en/media/downloads/) which allows to connect to any ODBC data source. Another approach is to use ODBC version of [Postgres Foreign Data Wrappers](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers). There are several extensions that implement FDW for ODBC data sources and they are listed on Postgres FDW page.